# Installing maui workload package not signed

Tags: installation, nuget, maui, .net-maui

Script:
dotnet workload install android ios maccatalyst tvos macos maui wasm-tools --disable-parallel --ignore-failed-sources --from-rollback-file https://aka.ms/dotnet/maui/preview.9.json --source https://aka.ms/dotnet6/nuget/index.json --source https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json --no-cache --skip-manifest-update --verbosity-d

Installing specific verions of maui preview issues in an error and rolling back action to previous the latest maui version( which is insatlled by default with vs 2022 preview)

My dotnet version 6.0.102

[image]

Why is this package is not signed : Microsoft.NET.Runtime.Emscripten.2.0.23.Node.win-x64.6.0.0-rc.2.21474.1 ?

Comment: You probably want to follow this guide: https://github.com/dotnet/maui/blob/main/.github/DEVELOPMENT.md also, remove all previous .NET 6 previews you have installed

Comment: thanks, but following that guide i get this situation where package is not signed :(

Comment: I see a bunch of options in your command that are not in that guide. Also, why are you trying to install preview 9? And did you uninstall all the .NET 6 preview versions? Did you run the NuGet cache clear command?

Comment: 1. unintalled all .net core sdks  2. clear all locals cache 3. insatlled .net core 6.0.102.   4. tried to launch script with administrator privileges command prompt .  I use prism for maui and currently only prism works only with preview 9 version and only for android as i have experienced.